# OutputFileResults returned by OnImageSavedCallback has an invalid Uri

Tags: uri, android-camerax

I am using CameraX API to take pictures in my android app, save them and then display them from their path. With the previous version `alpha-09` I was able to do so with `onImageSaved(File file)`. However with the `alpha-10` I have to use `onImageSaved(OutputFileResults outputFileResults)` and then get the path from the `uri` retrieved by the `outputFileResults`. But the Uri I get is always wrong. For instance when my image is saved at: `"/external/images/media/1581680878237.jpg"` I get the uri's path: `"/external/images/media/113758"`.

Here is my code:

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "NEW_IMAGE");
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");

                    ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions = new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
                            activity.getContentResolver(),
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            contentValues).build();

                    imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, Runnable::run, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                            Uri uri = outputFileResults.getSavedUri();
                            if(uri != null){
                                System.out.println("URI PATH" + uri.getPath());
                                System.out.println("URI PATH" + uri.toString());
                                activity.runOnUiThread(cameraProvider::unbindAll);
                                galleryAddPic(uri);
                                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                                params.putString("FILE_PATH", uri.getPath());
                                Navigation.findNavController(root).navigate(R.id.navigation_edit_image, params);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
                            exception.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I finally managed to save the image taken by ImageCapture by using an other method (especially an other ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builde). I didn't use an Uri object to save the image but a File object.

```
                File mImageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "YOUR_DIRECTORY");
                boolean isDirectoryCreated = mImageDir.exists() || mImageDir.mkdirs();
                if(isDirectoryCreated){
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/YOUR_DIRECTORY", "YOUR_IMAGE.jpg");
                    ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder outputFileOptionsBuilder =
                            new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(file);
                    imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptionsBuilder.build(), Runnable::run, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                            Bundle params = new Bundle();
                            params.putString("FILE_PATH", file.getPath());
                            Navigation.findNavController(root).navigate(R.id.navigation_edit_image, params);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
                            exception.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Be aware that if you use outputFileResults.getSavedUri() with this method you will always have a null uri.

Comment: This approach worked for me although the null savedUri through me off big time.

Comment: were you able to fix the null savedUri ? @speedynomads

Comment: Yes it worked even though the savedUri was null. See the answer below. In some case the the savedUri is expected to be null. It doesn't always mean that the take/save image action was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 8):

As of CameraX alpha 10, ImageCapture supports 3 types of save location: File, MediaStore URI and OutputStream, depending on which `OutputFileOptions.Builder()` is used.

The `Uri` field in `OutputFileResults` is only populated if the `OutputFileOptions` is MediaStore URI type. For `File` type, the caller should have the save location already, there is no need to return the info; for OutputStream type, the save location is unknown to CameraX. See the JavaDoc:

> public Uri getSavedUri ()
>
> Returns the Uri of the saved file.
>
> This field is only returned if the ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions is
>   backed by MediaStore constructed with #Builder(ContentResolver, Uri,
>   ContentValues).

For more info, please checkout the [developer doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture.OutputFileResults).

Comment: That would explain the null savedUri. Thanks